# How to make Yum work on virtual centos 6 on ESXi behind proxy?

Tags: linux, centos, proxy, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

I have ESXi in my LAN. All traffic from LAN is passed through a proxy. After installing Centos (network card in bridge)(VM on ESXi) I modified yum.conf for using proxy

> proxy=http://myproxy:3128/

Executing `yum update` gives me error:

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
>   Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>   Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error >was
>   14: HTTP Error 403 : http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os 
>   Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base

Next set up proxy globaly by executing:

> export http_proxy=http://myproxy:3128/

It also did not help :/

I'm wondering what is a problem ....any steal box behind proxy with set up proxy in yum.conf works perfectly. Could I missed some ESXi configuration for using it behind proxy (is there a way to set up proxy in ESXi ?? or i'm talking total nonsense)

I can log using ssh from my LAN to VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your log files on your proxy server, and the local messages file on the system you are installing on.  It is likely you are seeing some other networking error.  Does a simple web request like curl work with the given proxy?  Can you use curl to pull the mirror list?  Also does your proxy require authentication?  Also another thing to point out, sometimes the mirror list file points to ftp sites, thus you will need to have FTP allowed through your proxy.  It could be your other hosts were never directed to an FTP server so it has not been an issue until now.

Also for the hosts which you say do work through the proxy, are you sure they are actually going through the proxy, and not just bypassing it due to a side effect in yum because there is a direct route to the Internet for them?

Comment: problem was with proxy server thanks for fast help